# Communicate between two macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Is it possible to verify with macro `foo` that macro `bar` was called twice?

In more details:

```
trait Foo {
    foo() 
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    bar()
    bar()
}
```

I would like it to compile only if `bar()` was called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure—macros can maintain mutable state just like any other Scala code:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Macros {
  var counter = 0

  def foo_impl(c: Context)(): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    if (counter == 2) c.Expr[Unit](q"()") else c.abort(
      c.enclosingPosition,
      "Didn't call bar twice!"
    )
  }

  def bar_impl(c: Context)(): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    counter += 1
    c.Expr[Unit](q"()")
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> def bar() = macro Macros.bar_impl
defined term macro bar: ()Unit

scala> def foo() = macro Macros.foo_impl
defined term macro foo: ()Unit

scala> foo()
<console>:14: error: Didn't call bar twice!
              foo()
                 ^

scala> bar()

scala> foo()
<console>:14: error: Didn't call bar twice!
              foo()
                 ^

scala> bar()

scala> foo()
```

This seems like a really bad idea, but you could do it if you really wanted to.

Comment: Great thanks. Is it possible to scope the counter to concrete class definition? For example `bar` will be called in definition of `Bar1` and `Bar2`. Maybe something from context we can use as a map key?

Comment: I have found `c.internal.enclosingOwner` :)